# ByteArrayOutputStream uploaded to server

Tags: java, http, jpeg

I am working on an applet that interfaces with a signature pad.  The signature pad API has a function that returns a BufferedImage (assume its called API_CALL_TO_RETURN_BUFFERED_IMAGE()).  I can encode to jpeg and write this image to file just fine (Using FileOutputStream).  However, instead of writing to the local disk, I need to upload the jpeg-encoded image to the server.  I can POST data to the server just fine, and I can encode the image just fine; but I am struggling in having the two tasks meet in the middle.

The following is a condensed version of the code (try-catch, function, classes omitted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JPEGImageEncode jie = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(baos);
jpeg.encode(API_CALL_TO_RETURN_BUFFERED_IMAGE());         // assume magic

// baos now contains jpeg data

URLConnection urlc = new URL(some_url).openConnection();
// set up urlc request headers and such
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(???);   // ??? should be image=[the data in baos above]

// close stuff
```

Originally, I thought:

```
String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("image=" + new String(baos.toByteArray()), some_charset);
dos.writeBytes(post_data);
```

But that clearly distorts the image.

[This is what the proper (written locally) image looks like](https://imgur.com/k6iCZ.jpg)

I can only post one hyperlink, but the distorted image is here: imgur.com/mbmJL.jpg

**How do I write a ByteArrayOutputStream to a DataOutputStream?**

EDIT/UPDATE:

My solution was to do a mutlipart POST.  The reason for setting the Content-Type header as multipart/form-data was, as this link, http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4, says:

> multipart/form-data should be used for files, non-ascii values, or binary data

As far as writing a ByteArrayOutputStream to a DataOutputStream, it looks like:

```
dos.writeBytes(baos.toByteArray());
```

I am sure that is trivial to full-time Java programmers, but not I!

I did not use the library that was suggested because it offered way more then I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simplify some of the above by using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) to manage the posting. Here's the [Post](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html) tutorial and (if you need it) the [Multipart Post](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/multipartpost.html) tutorial. It's not clear which you need, but using HttpClient will solve a lot of the issues in creating the structure and content of an HTTP request.

Comment: HttpClient is very convenient and easy to use, thats true)

Comment: You know, originally, I thought the problem was my java (I dont write a lot of it), but now I am thinking the problem is decoding the image data on the server.

Answer (score 0):

When you write one stream to another, there's a lot of overhead that might come into it; buffers, try/catch blocks, .close(), more try/catch blocks.

[Apache Commons IO Library](http://commons.apache.org/io/description.html) automates most of it for you.

If you're not in a hurry, figure out how to do it, but in the long run, just use Commons IO.  For an example of how a buffered copy works, the first example from the Commons IO page shows the first half; instead of System.out.println, you'd want to write the line to another stream.

```
 InputStream in = new URL( "http://jakarta.apache.org" ).openStream();
 try {
   InputStreamReader inR = new InputStreamReader( in );
   BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader( inR );
   String line;
   while ( ( line = buf.readLine() ) != null ) {
     System.out.println( line );
   }
 } finally {
   in.close();
 }
```

If your file isn't string data, you'd want to read byte[] instead of String.